# Pyomo creating a variable time index

Tags: python, variables, optimization, indexing, pyomo

I'm trying to bring this constraint in my pyomo model
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOMmm.png)

I define a set for indexing over time and I want to optimize the corresponding energy variable below

```
model.grid_time = Set(initialize=range(0, 23)))
model.charging_energy = Var(model.grid_time, initialize=0)
```

My constraint definition looks like as follows:

```
model.limits = ConstraintList()
for t in model.grid_time:
    model.limits.add(sum(model.charging_energy[t] for t in model.grid >= energy_demand.at[t,"total_energy_demand"])
```

The problem with these codelines is that I'm summing over the whole indexing set model.grid_time and not just up to t. I think I need a second variable indexing set (replacing `for t in model.grid`), but I'm searching unsuccessfully after how creating a variable index set..

I would appreciate any help or comment!

Comment: The summation is mathematically nonsensical. You cannot sum over `t` from `t=0` to `t=t` (????).

Comment: Agree.  the constraint as written doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your're right the correct formulation is: ∑_(=0)^▒_^ℎ ≥_(,)^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
def Sum_rule(model, v, t):
    return sum(model.Ech[t2] for t2 in model.grid_time if t2 <= t) <= model.Edem[v,t]

model.Sum_constraint = Constraint(model.grid_time, model.V, rule=Sum_rule)
```

Essentially, what happens is that the `t` in the `Sum_rule(model, v, t)` makes sure that the constraint is called for each `t` in `model.grid_times`. The `t2` in the sum is also part of `model.grid_times`, but it will only take values that are smaller than the `t` at which the constraint is called.

I am not sure if my constraint matches exactly your notation, as you have not provided all the information required (e.g. regarding the subscript `v` of the `E^dem` variable, but it will basically do what you want with the sum.

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you a lot!!! Before your answer I had found a solution using a second index going trough a list of the timesteps, but your solution is more efficient and better style. Finally it wasn't very complicated but I hadn't thought about the if-extension..

Comment: There are in many cases more than one ways to solve a problem in Python/Pyomo, so I am glad you found my response helpful.